# Error using a read statement

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, fortran95

I am currently working on a FORTRAN program that is to read an input file. Once reading the input file, the first line of the file contains an integer representing the amount of matrices in the file.  The second line contains how many rows and columns each matrix has.  the rest of the lines contain the matrices themselves.  The program will read in each matrix and write it to an output file as well as calculate the sum of all the matrices.  When reading in the matrix data I keep receiving these two errors

> Code: READ(1,*,END=99)(DIMENSIONS(I), I=1,2)
>
> Error: Constants and expressions are invalid in read-only I/O lists.
>
> Error2: This label is undefined [99]

My code is:

```
  *START OF CODE
  PROGRAM MAIN

  *DECLARATIONS
  INTEGER EXISTS, DONE, NUM, DIMENSIONS*2, USED
  INTEGER I,J, TEMPMAT(10,10), SUM(10,10),OVER
  CHARACTER INNAME*30, OUTNAME*30
  *INITIALIZATIONS
  INNAME='NULL.DOC'
  EXISTS=0
  DONE=0
  I=0
  J=0
  OVER=0
  USED=0
  NUM=1
  *FORMATS
  5     FORMAT(' ','SUM OF 'I2,X,'MATRICIES')
  *MAIN CODE
  *DO (0)

  *DO WHILE(1) INPUT NAME !EXIST AND != QUIT
   DO WHILE(EXISTS.EQ.0.OR.INNAME.EQ.'QUIT'.OR.INNAME.EQ.'Q')
  *PROMPT FOR NAME OF FILE AND INPUT
  PRINT *,'PLEASE INPUT A FILE NAME INCLUDING AN EXTENSION'
  PRINT *,'ENTER QUIT OR Q TO EXIT'
  READ (*,*) INNAME

  *TEST FOR FILE
  INQUIRE(FILE=INNAME, EXIST=EXISTS)
  PRINT *, 'INPUT FILE EXSISTS'
  *IF EXIST=FALSE, DISPLAY MESSAGE 
  IF(.NOT.EXISTS) THEN
  PRINT *,'FILE DOES NOT EXIST, PLEASE TRY AGAIN'

  *ELSE EXIST=TRUE, OPEN (UNIT=1)
  ELSE 
  OPEN(UNIT=1, FILE=INNAME, STATUS='OLD')
  END IF
  *END DO(1)      
  END DO
  *ASK CHOICES FOR OUTPUT
  PRINT *,'PLEASE ENTER A NAME FOR AN OUTPUT FILE W/ EXTENSION'
  PRINT *,'ENTER QUIT OR Q TO EXIT'
  READ(*,*)OUTNAME

  IF(OUTNAME.EQ.'Q'.OR.OUTNAME.EQ.'QUIT')THEN
    DONE=1
  END IF
  *CHECK IF DONE (IF 1)
  IF(DONE.EQ.0)THEN
  *OPEN THE OUTPUT FILE DO(2)
        DO WHILE(USED.EQ.0)
            INQUIRE(FILE=OUTNAME,EXIST=EXISTS)
            PRINT *, 'OUTPUT FILE EXSITS'
  *OPEN IF FOR IF FILE ALREADY EXISTS
            IF(EXISTS.EQ.1)THEN
                DO WHILE(OVER.LT.1.OR.OVER.GT.2)
                PRINT *,'FILE ALREADY EXISTS. DO YOU WANT TO OVERWRITE?'
                PRINT *,'SELECT 1 FOR YES OR 2 FOR NO'
                SELECT CASE(OVER)
                CASE(1)
                    OPEN(UNIT=2,FILE=OUTNAME,STATUS='OLD')
                    USED=1            
                CASE(2)
  *DO NOTHING  
                CASE DEFAULT
                    PRINT *, 'THAT WAS NOT EVEN AN VALID INPUT, TRY AGAIN'
  *END SELECT
                END SELECT 
  *END IF FOR IF FILE ALREADY EXISTS AMD OPEN IF DID NOT EXIST, END DO(2)
                END DO
            END IF
            OPEN(UNIT=2,FILE=OUTNAME,STATUS='NEW')                   
  *READ IN 1 INTEGER (MAXIMUM VALUE OF 10) FOR # OF MATRICIES IN FILE
            READ(1,*) NUM
            PRINT *, 'THE NUMBER OF MATRICIES: ', NUM
  *READ IN 2 INTEGERS, 1=ROWS, 2=COLUMNS MAX OF 10 FOR EACH
            READ(1,*,END=99)(DIMENSIONS(I), I=1,2)
  *DO WHILE MORE MATRICIES EXIST DO(3)
            DO WHILE(NUM.GT.0)
  *READ THE MATRIX IN DO(4)
                DO J=1,DIMENSIONS(1)
                    READ(1,*,END=99)(TEMPMAT(J,I),I=1,DIMENSIONS(2))
  *END DO (4)
                END DO   
  *ADD MATRIX TO SUM MATRIX
  *DO(5)(6)
                DO J=1,10
                    DO I=1,10
                        SUM(J,I)=SUM(J,I)+TEMPMAT(J,I)
  *END DO(5)(6) 
                    END DO
                END DO
  *PRINT CURRENT MATRIX TO FILE W/ HEADER 'MATRIX X'
  *DO(6)
                DO J=1,DIMENSIONS(1)
                    WRITE(2,*)(TEMPMAT(J,I),I=1,DIMENSIONS(2))
  *END DO(6)
                END DO  
  *WRITE HEADING 'SUM OF ALL N MATRICES'
                WRITE(2,*)5,NUM
                NUM=NUM-1
  *END DO(3)
            END DO
  *END DO(0)
  END DO
  *PRINT SUM OF MATRICES
  *DO(7)
  DO J=1,10
    WRITE(2,*)(SUM(J,I),I=1,10)
  *END DO(7)
  END DO 
  END IF
  *STOP
  STOP
  *END
  END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimensions is declared in a peculiar way.  Try dimensions (2).   Maybe this has something to do with it since the line with the error message is the first to use dimensions.

Comment: That was a simple fix and worked.  Thank you.  First Time it finally compiled. Now I just need to resolve my syntax as i am now receiving a stack dump

Comment: Try compiling with your compiler's option to perform run-time subscript checking.  That may catch the cause of the stack dump. What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Uh, I think it wants to go to line "99" on EOF.

And you haven't defined a line 99 yet, have you?

Suggestion: try putting in a line "99 CONTINUE".

This link might also help:

- http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/format.html

Comment: What I am wanting to happen is for it to stop reading the current line after 99 characters

Comment: i have tried omitting the END however i still receive the error that constants and expressions are invalid

Comment: If you only want to read at most 99 characters per line, read into a string of length 99, then read your numbers from that string.  This will be more complicated than just reading your numbers from the file, particularly if the number of numbers per line is allowed to vary.

Comment: Dude - did you notice the error msg "Error2: This label is undefined [99]"?  Didu